# Angular CLI Unit Testing An Extended Window Method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli

I am trying to write a unit test for an Angular CLI (v6.0.8, with `@angular/core` v6.0.9) component that calls a method on the window object injected via a service, but I'm running into some issues.

Here is the component:
`MyComponent`

```
import { WindowRefService} from '../../services/window-reference/window-reference.service'

export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private windowRef: WindowRefService) {}

  addAnother() {
    if ((this.windowRef.nativeWindow._thirdPartyWindowObject) {
      this.windowRef.nativeWindow._thirdPartyWindowObject.track("toolstart")
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the service: `WindowRefService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

export interface ICustomWindow extends Window {
  _thirdPartyWindowObject: {
    track: Function
  }
}

function getWindow (): any {
    return window
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRefService {
    get nativeWindow (): ICustomWindow {
        return getWindow()
    }
}
```

This service is a way to extend the `Window` type to include a third party library introduced into the window object in the page the app is loaded into. Not ideal, I know, but it's the  use case I was handed.

This is the test I've written for the `addAnother` method:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'

import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent'
import { WindowRefService, ICustomWindow } from '../../services/window-reference/window-reference.service'

class WindowServiceMock {
  get nativeWindow (): ICustomWindow {
    return {
      ...window,
      _thirdPartyWindowObject: {
        track: (props: string) => {
          console.log('props', props)
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>
  let windowSpy: WindowServiceMock

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
    })
    .overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: WindowRefService, useClass: WindowServiceMock }
        ]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    windowSpy = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(WindowRefService) as any
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should call the third party scripts', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(windowSpy.nativeWindow._thirdPartyWindowObject, 'track')
    component.addAnother()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

This all works perfectly up until the point I would expect the `spy` for `windowSpy.nativeWindow._thirdPartyWindowObject.track` to have been called. When I check my logs, I can see the `toolstart` string being passed into the `track` method inside `WindowServiceMock` being logged out so the stubbed service *is* being called. However, for some reason, the spy is not.

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely obvious here, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? If so, what errors do you see?

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt The test error is:
    `Expected spy track to have been called.`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the *nativeWindow* getter is returning a new object every time it is accessed. So the function you spied on is not the same one that then gets called later. Updating the mock's getter to always return a reference to the same *_thirdPartyWindowObject* object, and hence the same child function, as shown below should fix the issue. Not sure if there is a better *the jasmine way* to do this though.

```
const _thirdPartyWindowObject = {
  track: (props: string) => {
    console.log('props', props)
    return true
  }
}

class WindowServiceMock {
  get nativeWindow (): ICustomWindow {
    return {
      ...window,
      _thirdPartyWindowObject
    }
  }
}
```